# Verify TDE implementation in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I've implemented Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) on one of my servers. However, how can I verify whether it has actually encrypted the data at rest and it is indeed secured?

```
select [name], is_master_key_encrypted_by_server, is_encrypted
from master.sys.databases
go
```

I've tried out the above query and it shows a 1 under the `is_encrypted` field for the `tempdb` as well as my DB. However, how can I prove this to a layman?

Only if I can show him the encrypted (scrambled) data. How to do this?

Comment: Try: Backup and restore the database on a new server without restoring a master key.

Comment: What if I try to restore it to a different database in the same server? Will it work?

Comment: Not sure, but I think it will restore successfully. You need a different server to prove the concept, as this what TDS defends against.